# Popup window not getting populated by list view

Tags: android, android-listview, popup

I am trying to populate my pop up window with a list view.But somehow I am not getting data.
Please help me out.

I am hereby using openPopup() function to start the pop up window and fillDataPopup()  is being used to populate data in pop up. Please let me know if you need any further details

Thanks

```
/**
     * FUNCTION TO SHOW LIST OPTIONS ON LISTS BUTTON
     */
    public void openPopup(){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.task_list_popup, null);
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);

        Button  btnDismiss = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.dismissBUtton);
        btnDismiss.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });
        fillDataPopup();
        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(listsButton, 50, -30);

    }

    public void fillDataPopup(){

        Cursor remindersCursor = mDBHelper.fetchAllReminders();          
        startManagingCursor(remindersCursor);                          

        // Create an array to specify the fields we want (only the TITLE)
        String[] from = new String[]{TasksDBAdapter.KEY_TITLE};     

        // and an array of the fields we want to bind in the view
        int[] to = new int[]{R.id.listNameTextId};                                

        // Now create a simple cursor adapter and set it to display -mapping layout with data
        SimpleCursorAdapter reminders = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.popup_lists_name,remindersCursor, from, to);   
        setListAdapter(reminders);
       // listNames.setAdaper(reminders);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What type of class is this? ListActivity, ListFragment? I don't believe you can use these classes to populate a ListView like this.

You need to use `popupView.findViewById()` to locate your ListView and the pass the adapter to this directly. Something like this:

```
listNames = popupView.findViewById(R.id.xxx);
```

and restore:

```
listNames.setAdaper(reminders);
```

Comment: my class extends listActivity like
public class TaskManagerActivity extends ListActivity

Comment: What modification u suggest shall I make..? Please be elaborate as I m new to android.Thanks

Comment: The ListActivity will not automatically find your ListView inside `task_list_popup.xml`. You must use the two steps aboves.

Comment: I think that did it..I understood that as pop up is having seperate layout I need to access the list view  of pop up in my main activity first..!! Thanks.